# Subsequent Start of Elasticsearch Docker Container Node

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

Although not a direct programming language question, this is an issue I have setting up my local development environment so it's closely related, and something I believe other software engineers will run into. So here goes, rather than installing Elasticsearch on my development machine (repeatedly for multiple nodes), I am trying - unsuccessfully - to create a **reusable** Docker environment.

I have an Elasticsearch cluster defined in Docker, using a Docker network. Essentially this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html, but for the sake of completeness I run:

```
docker network create elastic
docker run --name es01 --net elastic -p 9200:9200 -it docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.9.0
```

Everything comes up fine, so I add the second node:

```
docker run -e ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1g -Xmx1g" -e ENROLLMENT_TOKEN="<token>" --name es02 -p 9201:9200 --net elastic -it docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.9.0
```

This comes up fine as well and I see the second node running in the cluster by using `GET /_cluster/health`.

So now I `control-c` to get out of interactive mode and restart the container using `docker start es02` and it doesn't start. `docker ps` only shows es01. Running it interactively again (`-i`), I see:

*ERROR: Skipping security auto configuration because it appears that the node is not starting up for the first time. The node might already be part of a cluster and this auto setup utility is designed to configure Security for new clusters only.*

This is the crux of my problem. I thought perhaps it's still picking up the `ENROLLMENT_TOKEN` environment variable and that's causing it some consternation thinking it needed to enroll, so I committed the container and created a new container without that `-e` switch.  Same error.

For grins and giggles I tried to create the container without xpack security, adding `-e "xpack.security.enabled=false"`:

*ERROR: Skipping security auto configuration because it appears that security is already configured.*

Presumably because the elasticsearch.yml includes `true` by default. Anyway, has anyone run into this? Recognize the issue? Any ideas are welcomed!

P.S. I see the same behavior on Windows, Mac, and Ubuntu (Vagrant box).

Comment: The container doesn't seem to like `docker start` but prefers to start from a known-clean filesystem.  Can you `docker rm` the existing container, and `docker run -d` a new one in the background?

Comment: Same overall result. It works on the initial creation (just in the background), but subsequent starts throw that exception.

Comment: That sounds like you have an answer, then; never use `docker start` and always `docker run` a new container.  (I'd recommend that in general; since a container is a wrapper around a process, it doesn't cost much to delete and recreate the container.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I was able to cobble together is a little hacky, but it will get the job done.

Create or start your first/primary node as noted in the original post.

Generate an enrollment token `docker exec -it es01 /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token -s node`

Start a second stand-alone container `docker run -p 9201:9200 -p 9301:9300 -d --name es02 --ip 172.18.0.5 -e ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1g -Xmx1g" --net elastic -it docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.9.0`

Log into the new es02 container you just created `docker exec -it es02 /bin/bash`

Delete the configuration, passwords, and data:

```
rm config/elasticsearch.yml
rm config/elasticsearch.keystore
rm -rf data/*
```

Re-add the configuration file with just the cluster name, then start the node with the enrollment token you created earlier:

```
echo "cluster.name: \"docker-cluster\"" > config/elasticsearch.yml
bin/elasticsearch --enrollment-token <enrollment token>
```

Let the setup happen - you'll see a lot of JSON flying across the screen. When it stops, `control-c` and `exit`

```
docker stop es02
docker start es02
```

You can now start and stop the second node normally.